# Reading a Fragment from the Apollo Cache with client.readFragment()

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

After successfully executing a query, I can see the following (image attached) using Apollo Dev Tools.

However, I'm unable to query for a `filter` object directly with the ID, say, 2025. I'm getting an `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Can't find field filters on ROOT_QUERY object`.

[image]

Here's how I'm trying to query:

```js
client.cache.readQuery({
  query: gql`
    query Filter {
      filters {
        key
        value
      }
    }
  `
});
```

I also tried with fragment as follows:

```js
client.readFragment({
  id: '2025',
  fragment: gql`
    fragment filter on filters {
      id
      key
      value
    }
  `
});
```

But that gives me null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the object with the`__typename` and id that you are querying out of the cache. Notice that the id of the `filters` object is `filters:[id]` inside the Apollo Cache, that is the format you need to use to access that fragment in the cache, `[__typename]:[key]`. You can read more about assigning cache identifiers in the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#assigning-unique-identifiers).

You access your fragment using the following:

```
const filter = client.readFragment({
  fragment: gql`
    fragment filter on filters {
      id
      key
      value
    }
  `,
  fragmentName: 'filter',
  id: 'filter:2025'
})
```